# Merging Release Branches changes to trunk

Tags: svn

Here is my case:
First I have trunk, branches, tags in my repo.
I have release branch at branches/RB1.x
trunk has all lates codes being worked on. 
I needed to work on release branch RB1.x, so I made changes to it. Now how do i merge those changes to trunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard situation you have.

You can simply use the svn command to merge changes from a branch into the trunk:

```
svn merge -r x:y https://someserver/repo/project/branch/123 trunk
```

where `x` and `y` are revision numbers and `trunk` is a checkout of your trunk.

After having cleaned up any conflicts you can checkin the modifications. It is a good practise to use a standard revision comment that includes the merged revision numbers. That way it gets easier to identify what revisions have already been merged later on.

Comment: should i call svn merge from trunk or root of the repo?

Comment: Look at your revision history: `x` is the first revision after having branched the branch from trunk and `y` is typically the current `head`. Just think like this: "what revisions might have introduced changes to the branch that are not present in trunk". You want all of those. You can safely merge _all_ revisions since you merge from the branch, so only changes are considered that have actually modified that branch.

Comment: do i need to provide full url of branch? or is
svn merge -r 6:11 branches/rb1.x trunk same?

Comment: Make a fresh checkout of your trunk, cd into it and do this: `svn merge -r x:y https://someserver/repo/project/branch/123 .` (Note the trainling dot (".") in there, it is the current directory, your trunk checkout.

Comment: You need the full url, whatever that is. Where should svn know where to look for the branch otherwise? Remember that for svn a branch, a trunk and a tag are just folders in a filesystem. They have no special meaning in a technical sense.

Comment: thank you arkascha
can i not cd in to my trunk directly and do merge command there?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17831/discussion-between-arkascha-and-askkirati)

Comment: You can use ^/branches/rb1.x instead of full url

Answer (score 1):

Given you are not using svn 1.4 or older:

From trunk, run:

```
svn merge ^/branches/RB1.x
```

This is using the merge tracking feature, so you should be able to do this multiple times without getting the same changes merged over and over.

Or you can specify version ranges as arkascha explains.

Comment: I learned to prefer merging ranges since it produces less conflicts. Just my experience.

Comment: This will merge a range as well. The only difference is that it is subversion that finds your x and y based on where your branch started or which range you merged last time.

Comment: Sure, but that way you have less control, exactly because. When specifying the ranges manually you can merge longer periods chunkwise. Thus producing less conflicts.